# Framer Motion reorder failing silently with nested items

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have an array of questions that I'm trying to animate using Framer Motion. The shape roughly looks like:

```
const questionList = [
  {
    type: "text",
    data: {
      question: "What is your name?",
      valid: true,
    },
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    data: {
      question: "How old are you?",
      valid: true,
    },
  },
  {
    type: "multi",
    data: {
      question: "What are your favorite sports?",
      responses: ["Football", "Hockey", "Tennis", "Chess"],
      valid: true,
    },
  },
  {
    type: "single",
    data: {
      question: "What is your gender?",
      responses: ["Male", "Female", "Don't know"],
      valid: true,
    },
  },
];
```

I am rendering them in a list of cards using React and Tailwind like so:

```
export default function QuestionList() {

  const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState(questionList);

  return (
    <Reorder.Group values={questions} onReorder={setQuestions}>
      {questions.map((question, index) => {
        return (
          <Reorder.Item
            className="mb-4 px-4 py-6 bg-indigo-500 text-white ml-12 border-2 border-gray-100 shadow rounded-md cursor-move hover:shadow-md"
            key={`question${question.type}${index}`}
            value={`question${question.type}${index}`}>
            {question.data.question}
          </Reorder.Item>
        );
      })}
    </Reorder.Group>
  );
}
```

I'd like to be able to reorder the cards using Framer Motion `Reorder` components as described here https://www.framer.com/docs/reorder/ but every time I try the component tree crashes silently and I get a blank screen. When I reduce the questions to a flat structure like `['Question 1', 'Question 2']` etc I am able to get the re-ordering to happen. I suspected it could be something to do with the keys but playing around with that doesn't work. Grateful for any help/pointers

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use the loop index as the `key` in your `Reorder.Item`. When you drag to reorder the item, the index (and thus the key) will change. That will make it impossible for `Reorder` to track which elements have been moved to where and is probably why it's crashing.

Instead use a value like a unique `id` property for each question. This way React (and Framer Motion) will know exactly which element was moved and can render it at the new position.

Here's a more thorough explanation:
[react key props and why you shouldn’t be using index](https://stephenweiss.dev/react-key-props-and-why-you-shouldnt-be-using-index)

Answer (score 4):

Besides the key having to be unique, you also should set value from Reorder.Item to `value={question}`. If you want to generate a unique ID for each question, perhaps consider using a library such as [uuidv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4)